# Query to count dates and sum numbers at the same time

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have the following data in Access 2003:

```
Emp_ID  Name          WorkDays   TotalOT
------  ------------  ---------  -------
6       Dobles        1/25/2014  0
6       Dobles        1/27/2014  1.5
6       Dobles        1/28/2014  5
6       Dobles        1/29/2014  0
6       Dobles        1/30/2014  1
7       Alfaro        1/25/2014  4
7       Alfaro        1/27/2014  3.5
7       Alfaro        1/28/2014  0
7       Alfaro        1/29/2014  1
7       Alfaro        1/30/2014  5
7       Alfaro        1/31/2014  0
```

I am trying to build a query with a result that looks like this:

```
Emp_ID  Name          WorkDays   TotalOT
------  ------------  ---------  -------
6       Dobles        5          7.6
7       Alfaro        6          13.5
```

So far here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    (Employee_Tbl.EmployeeID) AS Emp_ID, 
    (Employee_Tbl.FullName) AS Name, 
    Sum(Attendance_Tbl.WorkDate) AS TotalWorkDays, 
    Sum(Attendance_Tbl.TotalOTHrs) AS TotalOT
FROM 
    Attendance_Tbl 
    INNER JOIN 
    Employee_Tbl 
        ON Attendance_Tbl.EmployeeID = Employee_Tbl.EmployeeID
WHERE (((Attendance_Tbl.WorkDate)>=#1/25/2014# 
    And (Attendance_Tbl.WorkDate)<=#1/31/2014#))
GROUP BY 
    Employee_Tbl.EmployeeID, 
    Employee_Tbl.FullName, 
    Attendance_Tbl.WorkDate, 
    Attendance_Tbl.TotalOTHrs;
```

but that gives me

```
Emp_ID  Name    TotalWorkDays  TotalOT
------  ------  -------------  -------
     6  Dobles          41664        0
     6  Dobles          41666      1.5
     6  Dobles          41667        5
     6  Dobles          41668        0
     6  Dobles          41669        1
     7  Alfaro          41664        4
     7  Alfaro          41666      3.5
     7  Alfaro          41667        0
     7  Alfaro          41668        1
     7  Alfaro          41669        5
     7  Alfaro          41670        0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do three things:

1. Remove the DISTINCTROW keyword.
2. Change the `Sum()` function to `Count()` for the dates.
3. Remove the date and OT fields from the GROUP BY clause. You only need to GROUP by EmployeeID and name.

The resulting query would be

```sql
SELECT 
    Employee_Tbl.EmployeeID AS Emp_ID, 
    Employee_Tbl.FullName AS Name, 
    Count(Attendance_Tbl.WorkDate) AS TotalWorkDays, 
    Sum(Attendance_Tbl.TotalOTHrs) AS TotalOT
FROM 
    Attendance_Tbl 
    INNER JOIN 
    Employee_Tbl 
        ON Attendance_Tbl.EmployeeID = Employee_Tbl.EmployeeID
WHERE (((Attendance_Tbl.WorkDate)>=#1/25/2014# 
    And (Attendance_Tbl.WorkDate)<=#1/31/2014#))
GROUP BY Employee_Tbl.EmployeeID, Employee_Tbl.FullName;
```

returning

```
Emp_ID  Name    TotalWorkDays  TotalOT
------  ------  -------------  -------
     6  Dobles              5      7.5
     7  Alfaro              6     13.5
```